# How to use predict within xyplot / panel function?

Tags: r, lattice, lm

I plot and fit data via

```
> xyplot(Amplification~Voltage,
        data = before_database[before_database$Serial_number==912009913,],
        grid = TRUE, 
        main = "SN = 912009913", 
        panel = function(x, y) {
            panel.xyplot(x, y) 
            fit<-lm(y ~ poly(x,2))
            panel.lines(x, fitted(fit), col.line="black")
        })
```

before_database is my data frame ( [before_database](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12593733/APD_data.txt.html) ) and via Serial_number I choose a grouped subset of the data frame. Hence, Amplification is against Voltage.

Now I have two questions: How do I get related values out of the lm fit ? At the moment I'm not quite sure which I need so I ask in general.
And, additionally, how do I get the corresponding value at a certain point out of the fit? E.g. I need the Voltage at Amplification = 150 (there is no data point). Fitted() should do it but I don't get along with it..

Here is the plot:

[image]

Thank you!

PS: I know the plot is not representing the data :) This is finally my task to find the best plot.

edit: According to the discussion I want to fit the model at first outside of the xyplot because of getting used to it. Therefore I have now:

```
before_database.frame<- read.table("APD_data.txt", 
                                  header = TRUE,
                                  sep = "",
                                  dec="."
                                 )

test.frame<- before_database.frame[before_database.frame$Serial_number==912009913, ]

test.fit<- lm(Amplification ~ poly(Voltage,2), data=test.frame)

xyplot(
      Amplification ~ Voltage,
      data = test.frame,
      grid = TRUE,
      main = "SN = 91200913",
      panel = function(x,y)
      {
          panel.xyplot(x,y)
          panel.lines(x, fitted(test.fit),
          col.line="black")
      }
      )

test.fit$coefficients[1]

new.df<- data.frame(Amplification=150)
predict(test.fit, new.df)
```

When applying "predict" I receive:

```
"Error in poly(Voltage, 2, coefs = list(alpha = c(247.536114864865, 174.327996600877 : object 'Voltage' not found"
```

I guess the frame "new.df" needs the variable voltage? But how do I provide it without a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To predict your response variable at a new value of the predictor variable(s) use the `predict` function rather than the `fitted` function.  You give it your model along with a new data frame that has the values of the predictor (x) variable(s) that you want to predict at.

Not sure what else you want to extract or what you want to do with it.  Running the command:

```
methods(class='lm')
```

will show you the functions that can be used on the results of an `lm` object, skimming the help files (then reading the interesting ones in depth) may help you find the information you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Will try to figure out some results! Can you please answer one question? I thought "predict()" is to..  predict "new data according to a given data frame or parameters or something like that"?

Comment: I just notice that I do not create an object in the above manner. Don't I need the object "fit" of the lm fit? How else do I access the fit (to use predict()) ?

Comment: @Ben, yes, that is what `predict` does, and what you asked for.  The corresponding point out of the fit is the "prediction".  The "fit" is the object returned by "lm" which you saved as the variable "fit" in your code above.

Comment: Thank you! But when I type ls() I only see one object: "before_database" which is my data frame. Do I have to extract the lm fitted object "fit" somehow out of the xyplot?

Comment: @Ben, your "fit" variable is local to the function, so you don't see it in the global environment.  You can either use it within the `panel` function, or fit the regression outside of the call to the lattice plot so that you have it for general use.

Comment: Where exactly do I place predict in the command line? Can't figure it out..

Comment: @Ben, That depends on what you want to with the results.  You could put it inside the panel function above either before or after the panel.lines call.  you need to either save the result to use later, or use it inside of another function.

Comment: At first, thanks a lot again! I need to save/store the results. I tried every position to put the predict command, nothing works. Is "predict.lm(fit)" with "fit" being the object at least correct?

Comment: @Ben, **what are you trying to do with the results of predict?**  If you want to draw a line or point in the graph then put it in the panel function (where the code for the line/point is).  If you want it outside of the graph, then run the regression outside of the plotting function and store it there.  If something else then tell us, we are not very good at reading minds.

Comment: I would like to draw two lines. One one the y-axis where I demand y=150 and then a line on the x-axis where I want the corresponding value. And both lines shall meet each other at the fitline.

Comment: @Ben,  then put `predict` in the panel function.  You will probably need to use `uniroot` with it to find the x value (actually values) that gives y=150, then pass the results to `panel.abline`.

Comment: Hi, at first thanks! Will go after that after getting predict work in principle. I updated my question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: I got it work in principle but only when Voltage is the predictor. But I need Amplification as the predictor.

Comment: Ok, got it also..  just swapped Amplification and Voltage in the lm fit. Can you please post your comments as an answer? Will accept them as a solution then. Thanks again!